# Failed prop type: The prop `rows` is marked as required in `ForwardRef(DataGrid)`, but its value is `undefined`

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

[image: Error]

[image]

Code is:

```
return (
    <div className="datatable">
      <div className="datatableTitle">
        Add New User
        <Link to="/users/new" className="link">
          Add New
        </Link>
      </div>
      <DataGrid
        className="datagrid"
        rows={list}
        columns={userColumns.concat(actionColumn)}
        pageSize={9}
        rowsPerPageOptions={[9]}
        checkboxSelection
        getRowId = { (row)=>row._id}
      />
    </div>
  );
```

I am creating a booking MERN app from a youtube tutorial by lamadev.
I am not sure what is wrong here.

Comment: Your list variable that your are passing in as rows is undefined. Probably you forgot to initialise it but I would have to see where list is defined.

Comment: import "./datatable.scss";
import { DataGrid } from "@mui/x-data-grid";
import { userColumns, userRows } from "../../datatablesource";



const Datatable = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const path = location.pathname.split("/")[1];
  const [list,setList] = useState();
  const {data,loading,error } = useFetch(`/${path}`);
  useEffect(()=>{
    setList(data);
  },[data]);
  const handleDelete = async(id) => {
    try {
      await axios.delete(`/${path}/${id}`)
      setList(list.filter((item) => item._id !== id));
    } catch (err) {
      
    }
  };

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialise the array here:

`const [list, setList] = useState();`

becomes

`const [list, setList] = useState([]);`

this is because of the way react works. The first time the code is run your fetch wont have returned a value.

Read about the react lifecycle. https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_lifecycle.asp

If you block the execution the code in the screnshot with a loading indicator then your error is that when you catch you completely ignore the error. So log the error and deal with it.

To have the page render without any list data do `rows={list ?? []}` to make sure that the list is empty rather than null/undefined.